# MATLAB Random Number Generator

Tags: matlab, random

I'm a beginner in Matlab and I can't solve the problem below.

"Starting with z (0,1) Gaussian Random variable; generate 10000 random variables with mean 10, variance 1; call it r6 vector.

At first glance, I tried to write r6=10+1*randn(10000,1); but I am not sure whether it's correct or not. Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: That's right. Looks like you have this nailed.

Comment: I'd only _add a `sqrt`_: `r6=10+sqrt(1)*randn(10000,1);`. Of course with `1`it makes no difference; I mean the general case

Comment: @LuisMendo Good point, overlooked that and the OP maybe too!

Comment: Also, the obtained random variables are _independent_. I assume that's what you need (otherwise you would have been given a correlation matrix)

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I'd like to ask one more thing. What if we start with z(0,1) uniformly distributed random variable, should I only change randn as rand? Is it enough?

Comment: By "start" I assume you mean which function you use. If you start with a uniformly random variable (function `rand`) and want to transform into a Gaussian variable, it can be done, but you need some transformations involving `log` and `cos`. That's a different question, and probably not what you want.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, randn is normally distributed ie z~N(0,1).

Comment: By assuming the question is "Starting with z (0,1) Uniformly Distributed Random variable; generate 10000 random variables with mean 10, variance 1; call it r6 vector." then the answer should be r6=10+1*rand(10000,1) or not? Many thanks.

Comment: yes, randn generates normally distributed. But now, I'm considering uniformly distributed random variables. So in this case, should I use rand instead of randn?

Comment: No. `r6=10+1*rand(10000,1)` would give you a uniform RV (not Gaussian) with std equal to `1/sqrt(12)` (not `1`)

Comment: `rand` samples uniformly from the range [0,1]

Comment: @LuisMendo why would the standard deviation be 1/sqrt(12). What should I do to generate uniformly distributed random variable with mean 10 and variance 1?

Comment: Why: just compute the variance of a pdf which is 1 in [0 1] and 0 outside that interval. Or see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29#Moments_and_parameters). To generate _uniform_ random numbers with mean 10 and variance 1: `r6=10+sqrt(12)*(rand(10000,1)-.5)`. I'll let you figure out why this is so :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can test whether you have the right mean and std deviation of your distribution after the fact with

```
 mean(r6)
 std(r6)
```

Note that as LuisMendo rightly points out you were issued the variance so you should make sure to take roots/square stuff as appropriate:

```
  variance = std(r6)^2
```

Comment: @Jason Also note that `mean(r6)` and `std(r6)` are the _sample mean / standard deviation_, which are only approximations to the "_true_" mean / standard deviation. So you should expect some deviations in the obtained values; those deviations will of course diminish with the size of `r6`.